# Problems to keep a `MultipartFile` in a View using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, multipartform-data

I have a file selector on my JSP form, like this:

`<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>`

When I select to upload a file it sends to the controller a MultipartFile throught a @RequestParam:

`@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file`

But how can I get back this file to the same View?

I tried to put `model.addAttribute("file", file)` on the controller, but it's not working.

Best regards,

Edited.

I have the following Bean:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: A file field will not retain its value, afaik this isn't possible.

Comment: See Jordi's answer below. You need to create a POJO bean with a MultipartFile file property/ivar in it. Create a constructor in the POJO that accepts a MultipartFile. Instantiate the POJO in the controller method using this constructor. By the way, what are you doing with the view? Are you passing it into a workflow, or do you intend to use it in a page?

Comment: @DanTheLion I tried the Jordi's way, I create the POJO, the `File` now were to be get from the `View` through a `@ModelAttribute('formName')`, but it just don't happen, the file don't come in the `@ModelAttribute`. I intend to use it in a page.

Comment: What will you be doing with the Multipart file once you have it in your controller method (writing to db, etc...)? I am trying to understand the intended application behavior. This will help me to correctly answer your question.

Comment: Hello @DanTheLion , I need the `MultipartFile` before send it to the Database. What I need is simple: it's a page that sometimes refresh and I must to keep all the data after refresh including the file selected.

Comment: Great, thanks for the details. How will you be using the file on the page? Just displaying name and size? You are going to need to write a method that saved the file to the DB. This method should take a MultipartFile as an arg. The return from the method can be a POJO view containing the file name, size and any other details you need for the page. Lastly, add this view to the model. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a helper class or a bean? If not I think you MUST create it... Then just add a new `MultipartFile` attribute with it's getters/setters:

```
MultipartFile document;

// getters & setters!!
```

Then in the view:

```
<form:input path ="document" type="file" name="Your file"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `HttpServletResponse` response in the method and write the file's content to response (defining properly the mime type.

```
public void processUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,
                            HttpServletResponse resp) {
    resp.setContentType(yourTypeHere + "; charset=UTF-8");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" 
    + theFileName + "\"");

    IOUtils.copy(new TheInputStreamFromTheFile(), resp.getOutputStream());
```